# Evil Queen - Good Queen?

Tags: shrek

In Shrek the Third, the Evil Queen is, well, the Evil Queen because she’s based on the antagonist from Snow White. But because she reforms at the end, can she be known as the Good Queen or would that get her confused with Snow White’s BIOLOGICAL mother? I mean, the Shrek Wiki once called her the Evil Queen/Good Queen, but the Good Queen part got deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean, the Shrek Wiki once called her the Evil Queen/Good Queen, but the Good Queen part got deleted.

All you can really conclude from that is that whoever made that change thought that it wouldn't be sensible to refer to her as the Good Queen, and that nobody has disagreed strongly enough to change it back.

For what it's worth, it doesn't appear to be common to refer to the Disney 1937 Snow White's mother as the Good Queen (the Wiki describes her as the [First Queen](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_Queen)).  However, a Google search on "Snow White Good Queen" does turn up the same link.  Also, according to [IMDB's cast list for the 1987 movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093999/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1) the corresponding character is indeed the "Good Queen".  So confusion would certainly be possible.

But in the specific context of Shrek, my guess is that if you started talking about the "Good Queen" people would think you meant Queen Lillian.  Again, a Google search ("shrek good queen") suggests as much - in particular, Google image search mostly turns up images of Lillian.

**Either or both of these might be the reason the edit you ask about was made.**

At any rate, I would not recommend editing it back.  On the whole, it doesn't seem to me to be a sensible choice.

This is probably not appropriate for a Wiki title either, but **if you need a way to describe the Evil Queen after she reforms,** I'd suggest either "The Previously Evil Queen" or "The Reformed Queen".

Or perhaps, if you're in a slightly more whimsical mood,  "The Queen Previously Known As Evil".